# struts2 don't display collections on jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tags

I'm start to learn struts2 and don't know many of it feachers help me please.
I have such action class

```
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String login;
    private String password;
    private Collection<News> newses = new ArrayList<News>();

    public String execute() {
        UserDao userDao = new UserDao();
        if(userDao.checkUser(getLogin(),getPassword())){
            NewsDao newDao = new NewsDao();
            setNewses(newDao.getAllNews());
            return SUCCESS;
        }
        return ERROR;

    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Collection<News> getNewses() {
        NewsDao newDao = new NewsDao();
        setNewses(newDao.getAllNews());
        return newses;
    }

    public void setNewses(Collection<News> newses) {
        this.newses = newses;
    }
}
```

and when execute method returns Success it redirected to `news.jsp`

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title><s:text name="news.page.title"/></title>
</head>
<body>
      <s:text name="news.page.main.label"/>
      <s:iterator status="stat" value="newses">
          <s:property value="title"/>
          <s:property value="body"/>
          <s:property value="user.name"/>
      </s:iterator>

      <s:include value="../jspf/footer.jsp" />
</body>
</html>
```

but in result it displayes something like this
[image]

and don't display my collection..(textfield and textarea with button from footer-page)
help me please tell what I made wrong
Thanks

Comment: why value="newses"? when your setter/getter is getNews? Shouldn't get/set insynch with attribute name?

Comment: Glad it helped you. I posted as answer. If it helped you accept by clicking on tick mark.

Comment: FWIW, "newes" isn't a word. It would be better-named as "newsItems" or just "news".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your getter/setter should in synch with attribute name.

Example:

```
getNewses()
{
...
}
```

not

```
 getNews(){ ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer.)

Three comments:

1. Your news items getter *also* instantiates a `NewsDao`, you should decide if you're going to do that in the getter, or the action's `execute` method.
2. You are tying your code to a specific DAO implementation. That's fine if you're just playing around, but in order to keep things testable and isolated from implementations, you're likely better off allowing the DAO implementation to be injected.
3. The `execute` method is not structured in a way that eases comprehension: fail faster.

```java
public String execute() {
    if (!userDao.validUser(login, password)) {
        return ERROR;
    }

    setNews(newDao.getAllNews());
    return SUCCESS;
}
```